# Volumes of Revolutions

Tags: integration, volume

I know that to find the volume I am essentially finding the sum of the volume of small slices of the shape through integration. But I am having trouble applying this theory. Can somebody help run through the solution for this problem so I can look thoroughly at the steps.

The triangle with vertices (a,a),(a,2a),(2a,2a)  is rotated

(a)  about the x-axis

(b)about the y-axis.

Find the volume generated in each case.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Or are you unsure on how to begin?

Comment: I'm unsure how to begin and unsure of the whole process really.

Comment: As a general thing, can you imagine the triangle be rotated around the required axes and the shape it makes?

Answer (score 0):

For example, with the washer method, integrate on slices of rings with area $\pi(r_2^2-r_1^2)$.

a) the volume integral is

$$V= \int_a^{2a} \pi[(2a)^2- x^2]dx
=\pi \int_a^{2a}(4a^2-x^2)dx $$
$$= \pi\left(4a^3-\frac13(8-1)a^3\right)=\frac{5\pi}{3}a^3 $$

b) the integral is

$$V= \int_a^{2a} \pi[y^2-a^2]dy$$
$$=\pi\left( \frac13(8-1)a^3-a^3\right) = \frac{4\pi}{3}a^3$$

Comment: Can you expand on the working side of things with the integration?

Comment: @user694587 - what do you mean by working side?

Comment: What the calculation looks like when you are substituting and a final solution.

Comment: @user694587 - worked out the integrals and added the results in the answer.